# Import CSV into Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, csv, import

I have a CSV file that looks like this:

```
Title,Content,Category
```

Is there a way I can import this file into Wordpress? Otherwise I might have to either write a script or do it by hand. Both of which I really would like to avoid.

Comment: why dont you use wordpress csv importer ?

Comment: I'll have a look at it again, but it doesn't seems to support what I need it to do

Comment: Nope, wordpress csv importer seems to be a load of... you get the picture...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WP All Importer - That worked ^_^ very nicely.